# Can I run LocalDb "in-memory"

Tags: localdb

I am using LocalDb in an integration testing environment - instantiating and disposing of my instance before and after my tests run.

However, when I create a database within my instance, it still flushes my tables and data to disk.  Is it possible to run LocalDb in an "in-memory" mode?  And if so how?

Comment: If you use transactionscope - https://github.com/ritterim/automation-sql

Comment: I'm not quite sure how the link helps (I searched the source code for "transaction" but found nothing).  My integration tests include "in process" services which do not propagate transactions - so running my tests within a single transaction will not help - but maybe I misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. LocalDB is still SQL Server, and in SQL Server there is no concept of an in-memory database. All databases are disk-backed, with in-memory cache sitting on top of them.

You could probably write a custom step in your testing harness to drop your databases after your tests are completed and delete database files. Maybe even it's already there if you're using TFS for build and test runs? But there's nothing in LocalDB to make it automatic.

Comment: it is actually not true that sql server doesn't have in memory with the GA of sql server 2014, but localdb still doesn't as far as i know.  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/solutions/in-memory.aspx

Comment: I don't think In-Memory features of SQL Server 2014 include in-memory **databases**. There are in-memory **tables**, but I understand that even if all tables in a database are in-memory, the database is still backed by a file with metadata, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You could run your tests against a database in a RAM disk. I have done that a while ago and it seemed to improve integration tests performance by a factor of 2 or 3! This was on a Windows 7 VM hosted in a MacBook Pro with an SSD. Your milage will probably be better if you have a mechanical HDD.

Since SQL Server allows you to specify the mdf file in a connection string via "AttachDbFileName=", you can leverage that by pointing to an mdf in a RAM disk.

The RAM disk device driver I used was ImDisk, which is available for both 64 and 32 bit Windows. Linux counterparts are numerous.